# Why am I getting "Unable to autoload constant" with Rails and grape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape

I want to do an API for an Android app. When searching, I found [{grape}](https://github.com/intridea/grape). I'm following [this tutorial](http://funonrails.com/2014/03/building-restful-api-using-grape-in-rails/), but I have a problem launching the Rails server:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:80
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:464:in `load_missing_constant': Unable to autoload c
onstant Usuarios, expected C:/Sites/appCerca/app/api/v1/usuarios.rb to define it
 (LoadError)
```

My directory:

```
app
..api
....api.rb
....v1
......root.rb
......usuarios.rb
```

and the files:

```
#application.rb
module AppCerca
  class Application < Rails::Application
      config.paths.add "app/api", glob: "**/*.rb"
       config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/api/*"]
  end
end

#routes.rb
AppCerca::Application.routes.draw do
  mount API::Root => '/'
  [...]

#app/api/root.rb
module API
    class Root < Grape::API
        prefix 'api'
        mount API::V1::Root
    end
end

# app/api/v1/root.rb
module API
    module V1
        class Root < Grape::API
            mount API::V1::Usuarios
        end
    end
end

# app/api/v1/usuarios.rb
module API
    module V1
        class Usuarios < Grape::API
            version 'v1'
            format :json

            resource :usuarios do
                desc "Return list of authors"
                get do
                    Usuario.all
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Why am I getting this error? I am using Ruby 1.9.3p484 and Rails-4.0.2.

Comment: Could you try to rename all `API` to `Api` in your *.rb files?

Comment: I tried but the same error:

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try either

- Moving your API code's files from `app/api` to `app/api/api`, or
- Moving your API classes *outside* the `API` module (i.e. deleting all the `module API` lines and their corresponding `end` statements).

From [Grape's documentation](https://github.com/intridea/grape#rails):

> Place API files into `app/api`. Rails expects a subdirectory that matches the name of the Ruby module and a file name that matches the name of the class. In our example, the file name location and directory for `Twitter::API` should be `app/api/twitter/api.rb`.

Thus the correct location for your `API::Root` class would actually be `app/api/api/root.rb`.

With this change your code starts and works fine for me on Rails 4.0.2.

Comment: i followed your recommendation of the second option as i didnt want api/api/ by deleting the 'module API' in all places under /api but it still getting 'uninitialized constant' errors

Comment: same issues... Unable to autoload constant Defaults, expected