# Expected ../app/api/api.rb to define Api in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, grape-api

I was trying to create an API using Grape. And for making this API work was referring to this website- [One Grape API](http://blog.elbowroomstudios.com/apis/). I even saw these [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319681/why-am-i-getting-unable-to-autoload-constant-with-rails-and-grape) on stackoverflow but its not working. 
The code is as follows:
*/app/api/api.rb*

```
  class API < Grape::API
   prefix 'api'
   version 'v1', using: :path
   format :json
   mount Code::Coding
  end
```

/app/api/code/coding.rb:

```
module Code
 class Coding < Grape::API
    resource :exam_questions do
      desc "getting all the questions"
      get do
            ExamQuestion.first
      end
    end
 end
end
```

/app/config/application.rb:

```
config.paths.add 'app/api', glob: '**/*.rb'
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app"]
```

/app/config/routes.rb:

```
mount Coders::API => '/'
```

But I keep getting this error

> Expected ../app/api/api.rb to define Api

Okay so now I moved the api files inside a folder named as Coders and there's no error.
So the file structure is like this:

app/api/coders/api.rb

```
module Coders
 class API < Grape:: API
  #code goes here
 end
end
```

And app/api/coders/code/coding.rb

```
 module Coders
  module Code
   class Coding < Grape::API

    resource :exam_questions do
    desc "getting all the questions"
    get do
         ExamQuestion.first
    end
   end

  end
 end
end
```

Now I have tried almost all permutations and combinations to access it but I am unable to get the path where I can access the questions, it keeps showing 404 error.

Running rake routes gives:
**coders_api_api/                                                                                Coders::API**

Is there any way to find out the links to access my methods.

Comment: I have got the answer to the question, after trying out with different links, finally it worked with this link : **http://locahost:3000/api/v1/exam_questions** without _.json_ and that was the mistake which I was committing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer to the question, after trying out with different links, finally it worked with this link : `locahost:3000/api/v1/exam_questions` without **.json** and that was the mistake which I was committing.